# Angular 2 ngFor won't update when object array changes

Tags: angular

I'm working on getting a json object array using an http get request. Currently, I have a list-view.component that calls a function, getEvents() in my event.service component. That function returns Promise, which represents the object array. It successfully returns the updated array to list-view.component, but for some reason, when I try to print out the array on console, it doesn't show the changes.

list-view.component.ts

```
this.eventService.getEvents(lat, lon, range, s).then(events => this.eventsList = events);
console.log(this.eventsList);
```

event.service.ts

```
getEvents(lat: number, lon: number, radius: number, s: string): Promise<Event[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.eventsUrl + "?s=" + s +"&radius=" + radius + "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as Event[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

If I try to print the array in the .then method, like below, it prints it correctly.

```
this.eventService.getEvents(lat, lon, range, s).then(events => console.log(events));
```

How come, when I try to print it after the this.eventService.getEvents() call, it doesn't have the new changes?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say thats because the `console.log`statement is executed before the promise returns. It works with `.then` because it`s executed **when** the promise returns.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.then()` is an async method, which means that the value returned can't be used outside of it. Everything you need to do with your `events` returned by your promise should be put within the `.then()`.

This if for the reason that your method is calling `.then()`, it will, but the `Promise` hasn't yet been resolved and the value hasn't yet been set.

Then your method will continue and print your `console.log()`. Some time (milli/nano-seconds) later, your async operation finished.

You could see it something like this:

```
fun test() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     console.log('Async operation ended');
    }, 2000);

   console.log('Normal operation ended');
}
```

which is basically what you created. Your method will call the `setTimeout()`, and immediately continue with the `console.log` **without waiting for the timeout to finish**.

To print the

> Async operation ended

Before, you should include it within your `setTimeout()` (in your case your `then()`)

```
fun test() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     console.log('Async operation ended');
     console.log('Normal operation ended');
    }, 2000);

}
```